# Is is possible to have strings evaluate as variables in groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am playing with grails and groovy. I wondered if its possible to do something like this.

```
def inbuiltReqAttributes = ['actionName','actionUri','controllerName','controllerUri']
inbuiltReqAttributes.each() { print " ${it} = ? " };
```

what would i put in the ? to get groovy to evaluate the current iterator value as a variable e.g. to do it the long way

```
print " actionName = $actionName "
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe off the top of my head, this should work:

```
print " ${it} = ${this[ it ]}"
```

Or:

```
print " ${it} = ${getProperty( it )}"
```

But i'm not at a computer to 100% verify this atm...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inbuiltReqAttributes.each() {
  evaluate("value = ${it}")
  print "$it = $value"
}
```